# Paths and Python question

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-path

I have a problem because I want to store some paths from images by using python 2.7 in Windows 10. Path are like this:

```
var1='C:/my/store/path'
```

and inside the final folder, where in my example is the name 'path', there are some images like these :

```
myimage_1010_im.png
myimage_1010_im1.png
myimage_1010_im3.png
myimage_1020_im.png
myimage_1020_im1.png
```

How can I connect my relative path as **var1** with the images using only the number of the mid name of images and, finally, to take the full original path as this:

```
var1='C:/my/store/path/myimage_1010_im.png'
```

I tried something but it didn't work.

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
my_file='1010'
path = os.path.join(cwd, my_file)
```

It didn't take full path.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Just use globe library:

```
import glob

var1='C:/my/store/path/*'

paths = glob.glob(var1)
```

List `paths` contains full path to each file in your `var1` directory. Then you can filter this list or whatever you want.

If you want to filter with midname just do:

```
my_file='1010'
selected_path = filter(lambda x: my_file in x, paths)
```

Comment: that contain path with the mid names ?where put my mid name for ex ?

Comment: i use glob library and after filter inside the final path ?

Comment: Just updated with filter function.

Comment: amazing but i test now and looks work but look something strange if i use my_file='2' for example then show me all files with the number '2' in name of files and show me more the shapefiles where in database have the number 2,why ?that is unexpectedly haha